# How do I move a ball up and down depending on a tap using SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

My code for my touches began function is this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let moveBall = SKAction.moveToY(380, duration: 0.4)
    let moveBalldown = SKAction.moveToY(293, duration: 0.4)
    if ball.position.y == 293 {
    ball.runAction(moveBall)
    }
    if ball.position.y == 380 {
    ball.runAction(moveBalldown)
    }
```

When I tap the screen, nothing happens.

I want the ball to move up and down depending on the tap.

The ball should move up on the first tap and then back down once it is at y = 380, and the screen is tapped again.

Here is the rest of the code that affects the ball.

```
var ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")

self.ball.position = CGPoint(x:40, y:293)
    self.addChild(self.ball)
    self.ball.yScale = 0.17
    self.ball.xScale = 0.17

self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height * 0.08)
    ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

var degreeRotation = CDouble(self.SBEBSpeed) * M_PI / 180
    self.ball.zRotation -= CGFloat(degreeRotation)

let moveBall = SKAction.moveToY(380, duration: 0.4)
    let moveBalldown = SKAction.moveToY(293, duration: 0.4)
    if ball.position.y == 293 {
    ball.runAction(moveBall)
    }
    if ball.position.y == 380 {
    ball.runAction(moveBalldown)
    }
```

Comment: Does inital position of ball is 293 or 380?

Comment: Initial position is 293

Comment: Could you post whole code? There are many other questions like does any other actions for other nodes works properly etc that would be easier to clarify by reviewing whole solution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touched SpriteKit in some time but I wanted to test your code. I'm currently running XCode Version 6.3.1, and I see they've updated the touchesBegan function to now take a Set of NSObjects. But your actual code inside the method runs just fine, so as long as you have set your "ball" to the right coordinates when it is initially rendered. Here is my working example:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var ball = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    var ballTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ball.png")
    ball = SKSpriteNode(texture: ballTexture)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 293)

    self.addChild(ball)   
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let moveBall = SKAction.moveToY(380, duration: 0.4)
    let moveBalldown = SKAction.moveToY(293, duration: 0.4)
    if ball.position.y == 293 {
        ball.runAction(moveBall)
    }
    if ball.position.y == 380 {
        ball.runAction(moveBalldown)
    }
}
```

EDIT: (Because I can't comment yet, and I didn't want to make a new answer) I ran your code after you updated it and the ball does not even appear on my screen. Is that happening to you when you say nothing is happening? The only problem was the x-position. I would recommend using coordinates that are relative of `self.frame`

Comment: My ball does show up in the correct position, it just stays still when the view is tapped. Also, when I use x coordinates relative to the frame, the same issue happens.